# Ajuda no cálculo de subtração com jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte campo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O objetivo é conforme for incluindo o adulto, ele vai somando os valores e quando remover campo, ele subtrai. Levando em consideração que o pacote é 150,00 e cada adulto é 50,00, o cálculo de adição está funcionando corretamente. O problema está na subtração. Quando tento retirar um adulto, o cálculo não está saindo da forma correta. Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
<input type="hidden" name="SubTotal" id="subTotalForm" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="ValorTotal" id="totalForm" value="">
    <table border="0" width="100%">
      <tr class='linhas'>
        <td>
        <table border="0" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td  style="padding: 5px">
              <select name="TipoPassageiro[]" class="form-control TipoPassageiro">
                <option value="">Tipo de Passageiro</option>
                <option data-tipo="1" value="Adulto">Adulto</option>
                <option data-tipo="2" value="Crianca6Anos">Criança de colo de até 6 anos</option>
                <option data-tipo="3" value="Crianca6a12Anos">Criança entre 6 e 12 anos</option>
                <option data-tipo="4" value="Adolescentes">Adolescente entre 12 e 18 anos</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          <td  style="padding: 5px"><input type="text" name="NomePAX[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome do pax" value=""></td>
          <td  style="padding: 5px">
            <select id="TipoDocumento" name="TipoDocumento[]" class="form-control">
              <option>Tipo de documento</option>
              <option value="Carteira de Identidade">Carteira de Identidade</option>
              <option value="Carteira Nacional de Habilitação">Carteira Nacional de Habilitação</option>
              <option value="Carteira de Trabalho">Carteira de Trabalho</option>
              <option value="Certidão de Nascimento">Certidão de Nascimento</option>
              <option value="Passaporte">Passaporte</option>
              <option value="Cédula de Identidade Estrangeira">Cédula de Identidade Estrangeira</option>
              <option value="Outros">Outros</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td  style="padding: 5px">
             <input type="text" name="Documento[]" class="form-control" placeholder="RG da pessoa autorizada" value="">
          </td>
          <td  style="padding: 5px">
             <input type="text" name="OrgaoEmissor[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Órgão Emissor" value="">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
          <td style="padding: 5px" valign="top"><button type="button" class="removerCampo btn btn-danger" title="Remover linha"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remover</button></td>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="3"><button type="button" class="adicionarCampo btn btn-primary" title="Adicionar item"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Adicionar mais passageiros</button></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    <div class="text-right">
      <strong>Valor do Pacote:</strong> <span style="font-family: Arial"> R$ 150,00</span><br>
      <strong>Valor Subtotal:</strong>
      <span style="font-family: Arial">
         R$ <span id="valorsubtotal">0,00</span>
      </span>
      <br>
      <strong>Valor Total:</strong>
      <span style="font-family: Arial">
         R$ <span id="valortotal">150,00</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center" style="margin-top: 10px">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">FINALIZAR <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></button>
    </div>
```

e o Jquery

```
     $(function () {
       function removeCampo() {
             $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
             $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
                if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
                   var campo = $(".TipoPassageiro:last").val();
                   //var valor_subtotal = 0;
                   var valor_subtotal = $("#subTotalForm").val();
                   var valor_total = $("#valortotal").val();

                   if(campo == 'Adulto'){
                    valor = <?php echo $visualizar[1]->ValorAdulto; ?>.toFixed(2).replace(" ",".");
                    var valorSubTotal = valor_subtotal - valor;
                    document.getElementById("subTotalForm").value = valorSubTotal.toFixed(2).replace(" ",".");
                    $("#valorsubtotal").text(valorSubTotal.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
                    if(valor_total == 150.00){
                       var valor_total = 150.00;
                       var valor_total = valor_total.toFixed(2).replace(" ",".");
                       var valorTotal = valor_total - valor;
                    }else{
                      var valor_total = $("#valortotal").val();
                      var valor_total = valor_total.toFixed(2).replace(" ",".");
                      var valorTotal = valor_total - valor;
                    }
                    $("#valortotal").text(valorTotal.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
                  }
                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                 }
             });
       }
       $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
          novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
          novoCampo.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
          novoCampo.find('select').val("");
          novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
          removeCampo();
});
$(document).on("change", ".TipoPassageiro", function(){
   // objeto com os preços separados por "tipo"
    var precos = {
       tipo1: <?php echo $visualizar[1]->ValorAdulto; ?>,
       tipo2: <?php echo $visualizar[1]->ValorCrianca6Anos; ?>,
       tipo3: <?php echo $visualizar[1]->ValorCrianca6a12Anos; ?>,
       tipo4: <?php echo $visualizar[1]->ValorAdolescentes; ?>
    }
    // inicia o valor total com 0
    var valor_subtotal = 0;
    var valor_total = 150.00;
    // laço que irá percorrer os selects e somar de acordo com o tipo selecionado
    $(".TipoPassageiro").each(function(){
       // pega o valor do tipo (1, 2, 3 ou 4)
       var tipo = $("option:selected", this).data("tipo");
       // só inclui na soma o select que tiver um tipo selecionado
       if(tipo) valor_subtotal += parseFloat(precos['tipo'+tipo]);
    });
    // formata a soma final com duas casas decimais separadas por vírgula
    $("#valorsubtotal").text(valor_subtotal.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
    var valorTotal = valor_subtotal + valor_total;
    $("#valortotal").text(valorTotal.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
    document.getElementById("subTotalForm").value = valor_subtotal.toFixed(2).replace(" ",".");
    document.getElementById("totalForm").value = valorTotal.toFixed(2).replace(" ",".");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código tem vários problemas. Em vários pontos você redeclara as variáveis, como por exemplo:

```
var valor_total = 150.00;
var valor_total = valor_total.toFixed(2).replace(" ",".");
var valorTotal = valor_total - valor;
```

Se você já tinha declarado a variável com `var` antes, não coloque novamente o `var`:

```
var valor_total = $("#valortotal").val(); // AQUI A VARIÁVEL FOI DECLARADA
...
valor_total = 150.00; // AQUI VOCÊ APENAS ALTERA O SEU VALOR (SEM var)
valor_total = valor_total.toFixed(2).replace(" ","."); // E AQUI TAMBÉM
var valorTotal = valor_total - valor;
```

Nesta linha, o seletor está errado:

```
var campo = $(".TipoPassageiro:last").val();
```

Vai sempre buscar o último select, que não corresponde ao do botão clicado. O correto seria:

```
var campo = $(this).closest("tr").find(".TipoPassageiro").val();
```

Irá buscar o select que está na mesma linha do botão clicado.

E aqui não está achando nenhum valor porque `#valortotal` é uma div:

```
var valor_total = $("#valortotal").val();
```

O correto seria pegar o texto e converter para número com `parseFloat()` (sem o `var`, como dito antes):

```
valor_total = parseFloat($("#valortotal").text());
```

Vai ficar assim:

```
$(function () {
       function removeCampo() {
             $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
             $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
                if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
                   var campo = $(this).closest("tr").find(".TipoPassageiro").val();
                   //var valor_subtotal = 0;
                   var valor_subtotal = $("#subTotalForm").val();
                   var valor_total = $("#valortotal").val();

                   if(campo == 'Adulto'){
                    valor = <?php echo $visualizar[1]->ValorAdulto; ?>.toFixed(2).replace(" ",".");
                    var valorSubTotal = valor_subtotal - valor;
                    document.getElementById("subTotalForm").value = valorSubTotal.toFixed(2).replace(" ",".");
                    $("#valorsubtotal").text(valorSubTotal.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
                    if(valor_total == 150.00){
                     valor_total = 150.00;
                     valor_total = valor_total.toFixed(2).replace(" ",".");
                    }else{
                      valor_total = parseFloat($("#valortotal").text());
                      valor_total = valor_total.toFixed(2).replace(" ",".");
                    }
                    var valorTotal = valor_total - valor;
                    $("#valortotal").text(valorTotal.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
                  }
                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                 }
             });
       }
       $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
          novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
          novoCampo.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
          novoCampo.find('select').val("");
          novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
          removeCampo();
});
$(document).on("change", ".TipoPassageiro", function(){
   // objeto com os preços separados por "tipo"
   var precos = {
       tipo1: <?php echo $visualizar[1]->ValorAdulto; ?>,
       tipo2: <?php echo $visualizar[1]->ValorCrianca6Anos; ?>,
       tipo3: <?php echo $visualizar[1]->ValorCrianca6a12Anos; ?>,
       tipo4: <?php echo $visualizar[1]->ValorAdolescentes; ?>
    }    
    // inicia o valor total com 0
    var valor_subtotal = 0;
    var valor_total = 150.00;
    // laço que irá percorrer os selects e somar de acordo com o tipo selecionado
    $(".TipoPassageiro").each(function(){
       // pega o valor do tipo (1, 2, 3 ou 4)
       var tipo = $("option:selected", this).data("tipo");
       // só inclui na soma o select que tiver um tipo selecionado
       if(tipo) valor_subtotal += parseFloat(precos['tipo'+tipo]);
    });
    // formata a soma final com duas casas decimais separadas por vírgula
    $("#valorsubtotal").text(valor_subtotal.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
    valorTotal = valor_subtotal + valor_total;
    $("#valortotal").text(valorTotal.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
    document.getElementById("subTotalForm").value = valor_subtotal.toFixed(2).replace(" ",".");
    document.getElementById("totalForm").value = valorTotal.toFixed(2).replace(" ",".");
  });
});
```

Exemplo de funcionamento sem os códigos PHP:

```js
$(function () {
       function removeCampo() {
             $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
             $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
                if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
                   var campo = $(this).closest("tr").find(".TipoPassageiro").val();
                   //var valor_subtotal = 0;
                   var valor_subtotal = $("#subTotalForm").val();
                   var valor_total = $("#valortotal").val();

                   if(campo == 'Adulto'){
                    valor = (50).toFixed(2).replace(" ",".");
                    var valorSubTotal = valor_subtotal - valor;
                    document.getElementById("subTotalForm").value = valorSubTotal.toFixed(2).replace(" ",".");
                    $("#valorsubtotal").text(valorSubTotal.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
                    if(valor_total == 150.00){
                     valor_total = 150.00;
                     valor_total = valor_total.toFixed(2).replace(" ",".");
                    }else{
                      valor_total = parseFloat($("#valortotal").text());
                      valor_total = valor_total.toFixed(2).replace(" ",".");
                    }
                    var valorTotal = valor_total - valor;
                    $("#valortotal").text(valorTotal.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
                  }
                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                 }
             });
       }
       $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
          novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
          novoCampo.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
          novoCampo.find('select').val("");
          novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
          removeCampo();
});
$(document).on("change", ".TipoPassageiro", function(){
   // objeto com os preços separados por "tipo"
   var precos = {
       tipo1: 50,
       tipo2: 20,
       tipo3: 10,
       tipo4: 30
    }
    
    // inicia o valor total com 0
    var valor_subtotal = 0;
    var valor_total = 150.00;
    // laço que irá percorrer os selects e somar de acordo com o tipo selecionado
    $(".TipoPassageiro").each(function(){
       // pega o valor do tipo (1, 2, 3 ou 4)
       var tipo = $("option:selected", this).data("tipo");
       // só inclui na soma o select que tiver um tipo selecionado
       if(tipo) valor_subtotal += parseFloat(precos['tipo'+tipo]);
    });
    // formata a soma final com duas casas decimais separadas por vírgula
    $("#valorsubtotal").text(valor_subtotal.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
    valorTotal = valor_subtotal + valor_total;
    $("#valortotal").text(valorTotal.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
    document.getElementById("subTotalForm").value = valor_subtotal.toFixed(2).replace(" ",".");
    document.getElementById("totalForm").value = valorTotal.toFixed(2).replace(" ",".");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="SubTotal" id="subTotalForm" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="ValorTotal" id="totalForm" value="">
    <table border="0" width="100%">
      <tr class='linhas'>
        <td>
        <table border="0" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td  style="padding: 5px">
              <select name="TipoPassageiro[]" class="form-control TipoPassageiro">
                <option value="">Tipo de Passageiro</option>
                <option data-tipo="1" value="Adulto">Adulto</option>
                <option data-tipo="2" value="Crianca6Anos">Criança de colo de até 6 anos</option>
                <option data-tipo="3" value="Crianca6a12Anos">Criança entre 6 e 12 anos</option>
                <option data-tipo="4" value="Adolescentes">Adolescente entre 12 e 18 anos</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          <td  style="padding: 5px"><input type="text" name="NomePAX[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome do pax" value=""></td>
          <td  style="padding: 5px">
            <select id="TipoDocumento" name="TipoDocumento[]" class="form-control">
              <option>Tipo de documento</option>
              <option value="Carteira de Identidade">Carteira de Identidade</option>
              <option value="Carteira Nacional de Habilitação">Carteira Nacional de Habilitação</option>
              <option value="Carteira de Trabalho">Carteira de Trabalho</option>
              <option value="Certidão de Nascimento">Certidão de Nascimento</option>
              <option value="Passaporte">Passaporte</option>
              <option value="Cédula de Identidade Estrangeira">Cédula de Identidade Estrangeira</option>
              <option value="Outros">Outros</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td  style="padding: 5px">
             <input type="text" name="Documento[]" class="form-control" placeholder="RG da pessoa autorizada" value="">
          </td>
          <td  style="padding: 5px">
             <input type="text" name="OrgaoEmissor[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Órgão Emissor" value="">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
          <td style="padding: 5px" valign="top"><button type="button" class="removerCampo btn btn-danger" title="Remover linha"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remover</button></td>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="3"><button type="button" class="adicionarCampo btn btn-primary" title="Adicionar item"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Adicionar mais passageiros</button></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    <div class="text-right">
      <strong>Valor do Pacote:</strong> <span style="font-family: Arial"> R$ 150,00</span><br>
      <strong>Valor Subtotal:</strong>
      <span style="font-family: Arial">
         R$ <span id="valorsubtotal">0,00</span>
      </span>
      <br>
      <strong>Valor Total:</strong>
      <span style="font-family: Arial">
         R$ <span id="valortotal">150,00</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center" style="margin-top: 10px">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">FINALIZAR <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></button>
    </div>
```

### Edição

Adicione um `value=""` na primeira option do select:

```
<option value="">Tipo de documento</option>
```

Comment: Show de bola Sam. Obrigado mais uma vez pela força!

Comment: @Fox.11 Adicionei um detalhe no final da resposta. Abs!

Comment: Certo. Obrigado.